# Loop multidimensional array and group results together

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table of events similar to:

```
+----+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| id |    date    | starttime | endtime  | location |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 2018-12-22 | 18:00:00  | 21:30:00 |        3 |
|  2 | 2018-12-23 | 18:00:00  | 21:30:00 |        2 |
|  3 | 2018-12-25 | 18:00:00  | 21:30:00 |        1 |
|  4 | 2018-12-21 | 07:00:00  | 10:30:00 |        3 |
|  5 | 2018-12-21 | 18:00:00  | 21:30:00 |        3 |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

What I'm trying to do is is list the details of each event grouped by location. For example, the data above would result in:

```
Location: 1
Date(s): 2018-12-25
Time(s): 18:00:00 - 21:30:00

Location: 2
Date(s): 2018-12-23
Time(s): 18:00:00 - 21:30:00

Location: 3
Date(s): 2018-12-21 | 2018-12-22
Time(s): 07:00:00 - 10:30:00 or 18:00:00 - 21:30:00 | 18:00:00 - 21:30:00
```

A standalone while loop displays each location separately unless I Group By in the query. If I do a check to see if the last location equals the current location, I get past the having to Group By in the query, but then I can't associate the dates and times with location if that location has multiple dates/times. I have been able to accomplish what I need by re-querying within the while loop, but I think there must be a better, more efficient way. Lastly, If you'll notice, I've used a " | " as a separator between multiple dates/times. Even when I get the results to list out as I mentioned above, I can't seem to get the last " | " NOT to display after the last listing.

Comment: its easy to use `GROUP BY` in query, for ignore data loss use `group concat`.

Comment: This can be done in MySQL using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), [`GROUP_BY`] & [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Or in PHP, save each row to an array, with the key being the location. Then using [`IMPLODE()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) you can create your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
Select group_concat(date seperator ,'|'), group_concat(starttime ,'|', endtime ) timings, location from tablename group by location order by location
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways

1. first populate the location

   ```
   q1 = "SELECT DISTINCT(location) FROM Table ORDER BY location;"
   ```
2. retrieve the first query with foreach

   ```
   foreach ($item in q1 ){
       //load again from location
       q2 = "SELECT date, starttime, endtime FROM Table WHERE location = ". $location .";"

       //print date only once
       echo "Date(s): ".date column;

       //loop the time
       foreach ($item in q2){
           //put the logic to create or by yourself
           echo "Time(s): ". $item->starttime ."-". $item->endtime;
       }
   }
   ```